Base class properties and methods from a library class are not being inherited into my subclass
I can't seem to properly inherit a base class into my custom class, in this case, the ServiceInfo class from the zeroconf library into my custom MdnsServiceInfo class. While testing out workarounds I created a local clone of the class, imported it, and it works (but not optimal), and when importing the original class from the zeroconf library, it breaks.
My custom ServiceInfo class (added one extra parameter, zc):
class MdnsAsyncServiceInfo(ServiceInfo):
    def __init__(self, zc:'Zeroconf', *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._zc = zc

I cloned the ServiceInfo class locally (copied/pasted from the zeroconf info.py file, only difference is the import paths).
original: from .._cache import DNSCache vs clone: from zeroconf._cache import DNSCache, etc
How the clone class is imported
from mdns_discovery.service_info_base import ServiceInfo

With the cloned import, all the methods and properties I need are available.
But when I import from the zeroconf library directly (which is what I'm trying to achieve)
from zeroconf import ServiceInfo

It doesn't pull in the properties or methods and gives errors like these:
AttributeError: 'MdnsAsyncServiceInfo' object has no attribute '_get_initial_delay'
Just some extra info in case it's relevant, this is the relative path of the original class in my setup (out/py is my Python environment):
/home/ubuntu24/myproject/out/py/lib/python3.12/site-packages/zeroconf/_services/info.py
Is this a common problem in Python?
